# Getting Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error when trying to shift data

Tags: excel, vba

There are multiple sheets in my workbook, of which I'm working on sheet >500 & sheet <500.

I'm trying to shift data in both the sheets after deleting 1 or multiple columns data. G1 to V1 contains date and keeps on changing. G1 contains today's date and H1 contains yesterdays date. I'm downloading data and keeping it in G2 to V983 for >500 & G2 to V598 for <500. Once day changes G1 changes to current date and so on. Since my data downloaded is only up to yesterday. So, I'm deleting the data from V2 to V(last row) from one sheet (>500) and cutting the data from G2 to U(last row) and pasting it in H2 to V(last row) of one sheet and doing the same for another sheet (<500).

I might open the sheet after 2/3/4 days. In that case, I need to delete data from 2/3/4 columns and shift data accordingly. So, I'm comparing X3 (downloaded data date) with G1, H1 and so on to shift data.
When I'm running the macro, its able to delete the data frim V2 to V(last row) for >500 sheet and able to cut data from G2 to U(last row) and paste it in H2 to V(last row) for >500 sheet. Its able to delete the data frim V2 to V(last row) for <500 sheet but unable to cut data from G2 to U(last row) and paste it in H2 to V(last row) for <500 sheet. I'm getting Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined in this line.
I'm not sure why I'm getting this error at all.

**Note**: There are some blank cells as well in both the sheets like suppose G50 to V50 is blank and G80 to L80 is blank and so on.

I tried clearing contents instead of deleting, but it didn't worked.

Here is my macro for reference.

```
Sub shiftData()
    
    Dim LR As Integer, LR1 As Integer, FC As Integer
    LR = Worksheets(">500").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    LR1 = Worksheets("<500").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    FC = Worksheets(">500").Range("V2").End(xlToLeft).Column
    MsgBox LR '938
    MsgBox LR1 '598
    MsgBox FC '7

    If Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("G1").Value Then
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("H1").Value Then
        'Worksheets(">500").Range("V2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range("V2:V" & LR).ClearContents
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 21)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 1)), Cells(LR, 22))
        'Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(LR, 21)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(LR, 22))
        'Worksheets("<500").Range("V2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range("V2:V" & LR1).ClearContents

        'Getting Error "1004: Application-defined or Object-defined" in below line

        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 21)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 1)), Cells(LR1, 22))
        'Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(LR1, 21)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("I1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("U2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 20)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 2)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("U2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 20)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 2)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("J1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("T2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 19)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 3)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("T2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 19)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 3)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("K1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("S2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 18)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 4)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("S2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 18)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 4)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("L1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("R2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 17)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 5)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("R2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 17)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 5)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("M1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("Q2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 16)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 6)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("Q2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 16)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 6)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("N1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("P2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 15)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 7)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("P2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 15)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 7)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("O1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("O2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 14)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 8)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("O2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 14)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 8)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("P1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("N2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 13)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 9)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("N2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 13)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 9)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("Q1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("M2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 12)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 10)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("M2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 12)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 10)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("R1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("L2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 11)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 11)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("L2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 11)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 11)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("S1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("K2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 10)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 12)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("K2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 10)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 12)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("T1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("J2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 9)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 13)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("J2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 9)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 13)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("U1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("I2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 8)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 14)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("I2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 8)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 14)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    ElseIf Worksheets(">500").Range("X3").Value = Worksheets(">500").Range("V1").Value Then
        Worksheets(">500").Range("H2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR, 7)).Cut Worksheets(">500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 15)), Cells(LR, 22))
        Worksheets("<500").Range("H2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 7)).Cut Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, (FC + 15)), Cells(LR1, 22))
    Else
        Worksheets(">500").Range("G2:V" & LR).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Worksheets("<500").Range("G2:V" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you redownload everything instead of doing all of the shifting? Another workaround would be to create new sheets and just copy the stuff you want into them and delete the original sheets.

Comment: To be frank with you, I have faced all sorts of problems using Excel as a sort of database. You would be better of using MS Access for that purpose. You can then entirely avoid this type of data manipulation.

Comment: @Tarik, I can download all the data but I need to download data for 16 dates and I thought since, I have data for 15 dates then why not shift them and download data only for 1 date. I don't know MS Access, hence can't do it using that.

Comment: When you get this error, go to the immediate window, type in `? Worksheets(">500").UsedRange.Address, Worksheets("<500").UsedRange.Address`, hit [Enter], and tell us what response you got.

Comment: @z32a7ul, I'm getting following response.  $A$1:$AA$983  $A$1:$AA$598

Comment: `Worksheets("<500").Range(Cells(2, FC), Cells(LR1, 21)).Cut` the `Cells()` are unqualified, they need a worksheet reference otherwise the default is the active sheet which probably isn't `Worksheets("<500")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the number of columns to shift by using a Do While/Loop then use resize and offset to determine the ranges to cut/paste

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub shiftData()

    Const COL_FIRST = "G"
    Const COL_LAST = "V"

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws, dtData As Date
    Dim rngDate As Range, lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim firstCol As Long, lastCol As Long, endCol As Long, cols As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Sheets("<500")
        Set ws2 = .Sheets(">500")
    End With
    
    With ws1 ' <500
       lastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    With ws2 ' >500
       dtData = .Range("X3").Value2 ' download date
       Set rngDate = Cells(1, COL_FIRST)
       firstCol = rngDate.Column
       lastCol = ws2.Cells(1, COL_LAST).Column
       lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Download date is " & dtData & vbLf & _
    ws1.Name & "last row=" & lastRow1 & vbLf & ws2.Name & "last row=" & lastRow2 & " first col " & firstCol
    
    ' calculate number of columns to shift
    cols = 0
    Do While rngDate.Value2 > dtData
       Set rngDate = rngDate.Offset(, 1) ' next column
       If rngDate.Column > lastCol Then
           ws1.Range(COL_FIRST & "2:" & COL_LAST & lastRow1).ClearContents
           ws2.Range(COL_FIRST & "2:" & COL_LAST & lastRow2).ClearContents
           MsgBox "All data cleared ", vbExclamation
           Exit Sub
       End If
       cols = cols + 1
    Loop
    
    If cols = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to move", vbInformation
    Else
        endCol = lastCol - cols ' 22=V
        
        ' cut/paste data columns for each sheet
            
        With ws1.Cells(2, firstCol).Resize(lastRow1 - 1, endCol - firstCol + 1)
             MsgBox "Sheet " & ws1.Name & " Moving range " & .Address, vbInformation, "Shift right " & cols & " columns "
            .Cut .Offset(, cols)
        End With
        ' clear any remaining data
        With ws1.Cells(2, firstCol).Resize(lastRow1 - 1, cols)
            MsgBox "Clearing " & ws1.Name & " " & .Address
            .ClearContents
        End With

        With ws2.Cells(2, firstCol).Resize(lastRow2 - 1, endCol - firstCol + 1)
             MsgBox "Sheet " & ws2.Name & " Moving range " & .Address, vbInformation, "Shift right " & cols & " columns "
            .Cut .Offset(, cols)
        End With
        ' clear any remaining data
        With ws2.Cells(2, firstCol).Resize(lastRow2 - 1, cols)
            MsgBox "Clearing " & ws2.Name & " " & .Address
            .ClearContents
        End With
    
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I missed your above solution which is much cleaner than mine, but when I run it. It's shifting data for ws1 sheet'<500' perfectly fine but for ws2 sheet '>500' it's shifting data only up to lastrow1 of ws1 sheet instead of lastrow2 of ws2 sheet.

Comment: Awesome. It's working perfectly fine now. Thanks a lot for quick response.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again. Actually, today when I clicked the macro twice by mistake it shifted two columns even though Download Date was 8/24/2023. So, I clicked few times and it keep on shifting the columns by 1 every time I clicked the macro. Could you please look into the Answer Code as I'm unable to identify any error in your code.

Comment: @faiz If G1 on >500 is equal to the download date in X3 then the macro should exit with "Nothing to move".  Do you have a cell where you can record the date/time when the macro was last run ? You could prevent the macro running if Column G row 2 and below is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly fine after if else.